# Is there a other, better way to call this js, which is coming from ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, eval

I would like to ask about eval() function, I have working code where I use this function, but I saw that is not good practice to be used. so I was wondering is there any other way to do that: I have response from ajax, this response is a web page, which contains a bit of js code inside. So when I parse this page in a div jquery removes all js, that's why I have id attribute of my  which is inside that page so i can access that code and than I execute with eval. I'll put some code for example:

```
success:function(data){
 $('title').html($(data).filter('title').html()); 
 var js = $(data).filter('#script').html(); 
 var page = $(data).filter('#content').html(); 
 $('#content').html(page); 
 eval(js);
}
```

So actually my question is there a other, better way to call this js, which is coming from ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to run the script. As long as it's in script tags it will run when it's appended to the page with `.html()` with the rest of the content.

Comment: I see your point, and I was thinking, it should work like this but it doesn't work. I don't know on what point Jquery removes the script I can see it when alert(data), but When I do var page = $(data).filter('#content').html(); the script is gone somewhere. I've tried to put it in a div with id and take  it from there, but same situation. That script contains itself a function that sets content to my ckeditor on one page, on other contains function that call dynamic table, so these functions they always get different parameters that's why I can't put them in my header